# Can I use the same SD card from my original pi 3 with another pi 3

Tags: sd-card

Let's say my pi broke. Can I use the SD card with everything I already have on it with a brand new pi that is of the same model?

I know you can't if the models are different but I can't get a clear answer online but I assume you would, right?

Sorry I'm a noob

Comment: yes you can without any problems

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Indeed if you have a card which works on a Pi3 it will work on all Pi models.

There are a few restrictions; if you have purchased licences for MPEG2 etc these are specific to a Pi. Some distributions e.g. Ubuntu will not work on earlier models.

It is possible to configure the OS in such a way that operations will differ between models or individual Pi, but in general they should boot.

You should not attempt to run the same image on multiple Pi; they should have individual hostnames and not attempt to use the same IP addresses.